# How to Secure connection between JTDS and SQL using android

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, jtds

I created new application using Kotlin by Android Studio and I have a connection between my and SQL server Database.

The problem is Anyone can unpack my APK file and see my Connection Info
like SQL Server IP and database name and user and password of this database
i want to secure this Connection Info and none can see it. How can I do so?

Comment: Help Me please i want to hide my connection info

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an API on the server and thus your Android application will only know how to connect the API, while the db data will be known by the API only. This would mean a restructuring of your project, so instead of being connected directly to a database you will only be connected to the API.

Comment: can you please give me example please?
im new

Comment: @AhmedElsayed I mainly gave you an idea, which you can use in general. However, to resolve this issue for your exact project, you will need to do further research. Search for tutorials which are about API usage on Android (like https://www.javahelps.com/2018/12/access-mysql-from-android-through.html) on one side and API development (like https://dzone.com/articles/api-development-an-introductory-guide) on the other side of the problem.